# How to stop freeze listView

Tags: android, listview

i have a listView with a custom BaseAdapter.Every list item has a clickable button.
    private List items = new ArrayList();

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = null;
        try {
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);

            TextView name = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            name.setText(items.get(position).getName());


            imageButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.Button);
            imageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // do something
                }
            });

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return v;
    }
```

My problem is that the app freezes when i scroll the list. 
How can i fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're creating a new view everytime which is the complete opposite of what a listview does, it reuses views.

Remove `View v = null` and use the `convertView` parameter passed in.

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView == null){
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
    }

    TextView name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    name.setText(items.get(position).getName());

    imageButton = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Button);
    /* NB
    For efficiency sake see the link in Sparky's answer about itemClickListeners
    instead of using onClickListeners
    */
    imageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // do something
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: This still creates a new `OnClickListener` on every call to `getView()`, i.e. at least for every row.

Comment: You could even improve on this by using the ViewHolder pattern. http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List14.html

Answer (score 3):

See the [Hello, ListView tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html) for an example of capturing touches on the ListView itself, rather than each individual row.